# What "reviewed this 43 mins ago: Reviewed" means for a suggested edit?

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

On *English Language & Usage* I found [a suggested edit](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12196), for which the review activity is described as:

> Luke reviewed this 46 mins ago: Reviewed

What does that mean?
Why isn't the suggested edit declined, nor accepted?

The user who reviewed the suggested edit (which is for [I should think you'd have](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90484/i-should-think-youd-have)) is not the OP. What is more strange is that https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12196 doesn't show what the suggested edit was.

[image: screenshot]

The question is still open; [it has never been closed](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/90484/revisions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is fixed – the [link in question](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12196) 404s now, as expected.

Review ids are unique per site, not per queue. If you manage to generate an invalid url, we now serve a Page Not Found, rather than a nonsensical page as you were getting.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a suggested edit. It's a *First Posts* review, for which the **Reviewed** action is appropriate.

If you got to [the reviewer's profile](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/24168/luke?tab=activity&sort=reviews), it's listed as a *First Posts* review, not a *Suggested Edits* review. The link there is not the same as the one in your post; his profile links to: [`/review/first-posts/12196`](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/12196) instead of [`/review/suggested-edits/12196`](https://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/12196).

Where did you get that link? Maybe there is a bug that generated the wrong URL.

Comment: Oh! I was looking for strange suggested edits done from anonymous users, and simply decreased the number I get from another suggested edit. I thought every review queue had their own IDs.